# Are the following two ideals equal? How to prove it, or show they are not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$I= \langle x-y^2, x-y^3, x-y^4,... \rangle, $ and $J=\langle x-y^2, x-y^3\rangle$.

Obviously $J \subset I$, but what about the reverse inclusion?

Comment: $J=(x,y^2)\cap (x-y^2, 1-y)$. Can you show that $I$ is contained in both these ideals occurring in the intersection?

Comment: @Mohan, I honestly have no idea. And don't follow how you obtained that expression for $J$ either. Can you please give more details?

Comment: $(x-y^2, x-y^3)=(x-y^2, y^2-y^3)=(x-y^2, y^2(1-y))$. Since $y^2, 1-y$ are comaximal, by Chinese remainder theorem, one has the last equal to $(x-y^2, y^2)\cap (x-y^2, 1-y)$, which gives what I said.

Comment: @Mohan but that is not the same as what you wrote above, and also I would like if you will explain how the containment of $I$ follows. How does $(x-y^2, x-y^3)= (x-y^2, y^2 - y^3)$?

Comment: How does $(x-y^2, x-y^3)= (x-y^2, y^2 - y^3)$?

Comment: Notice that $(x,y^2) = (x-y^2,y^2)$, so what Mohan says is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice example for Hilbert Basis. Anyway take $x-y^2$ and $x-y^3$ and subtract them to get $y^3-y^2$, now multiply by $y$ (its an ideal) so you get $y^4-y^3$ subtract this from $x-y^3$ and you get $x-y^4$. The rest should now be clear.

Comment: Nice work. Is there a similar/elegant way to show $I$ is not radical, or do I compute the Groebner basis?

Comment: what do you mean radical ? $I=\sqrt{I}$ ?

Comment: I mean $I \not= \sqrt{I}$. You can compute the reduced Groebner basis for each and show they're not equal.

Comment: @user264885 It's trivial to show that $J$ is not radical, so $I$ is also not radical.

Comment: @user26857 I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: @user26857 Sorry, why is $J$ trivially not radical ?

Comment: Because $y^2(1-y)^2\in J$ and $y(1-y)\notin J$.

Answer (score 2):

$$K[X,Y]/I\simeq\frac{K[X,Y]/(X-Y^2)}{I/(X-Y^2)}\simeq K[Y]/(Y^2-Y^3,Y^2-Y^4,\dots)=K[Y]/(Y^2-Y^3)$$

$$K[X,Y]/J\simeq\frac{K[X,Y]/(X-Y^2)}{I/(X-Y^2)}\simeq K[Y]/(Y^2-Y^3)$$

But if $R$ is a noetherian ring, and $J\subset I$ are ideals of $R$ such that $R/J\simeq R/I$ then $J=I$.